# CNTK Low GPU utilisation training via C++ API

Tags: c++, gpu, cntk

I've written some fairly standard CNTK code to train a simple feed forward network using the C++ API. During training I get a speed up of about 4 times using GPU over CPU (CPU is 100% utilised) but that is with virtually zero GPU utilisation during training when I use GPU. Using the CNTK C++ APIs how can one increase GPU utilisation? My results are fine but seemingly too slow.

I'm running CNTK on a recent Lenovo, Windows 10, Intel CPU, Quadro P3200.
I'm applying CNTK to in-memory data generated on the fly in my program.
Simple dataset with 2 scalar features and 1 scalar label data, say 10,000 items. The data is actually generated from Monte Carlo simulations.
As there is no C++ reader API for in-memory data I'm using the Value::CreateSequence API to create data to pass to the trainer. Note the data is created on the card, read only (assuming 'device' parameter is GPU(0)) to reduce host/card transfers. The data structures are originally C++ eigen matrices. I'm using Nesterov learner in the code sample but have tried SGD and SGD with momentum with similar results. All calcs are using float which should be fast on the Quadro.

```
void RMLearning::OLSDeepLearning(const MatrixXd& X, const MatrixXd& Y, const DeviceDescriptor& device)
{

    auto inputVarName = L"features";
    auto inputVar = InputVariable({ m_inputDim }, DataType::Float, inputVarName);
    auto regressionOutput = FullyConnectedFeedForwardRegressionNet(inputVar, m_outputDim, m_hiddenLayersDim, m_numHiddenLayers, device, m_nonLinearity, L"regressionOutput");

    auto labelsVarName = L"Labels";
    auto labelsVar = InputVariable({ m_outputDim }, DataType::Float, labelsVarName);


    auto trainingLoss = ReduceSum(CNTK::SquaredError(regressionOutput, labelsVar, L"SquaredErrorLossFunction"), Axis::AllAxes(), L"SquaredErrorLossFunction");

    if (m_SaveAndReLoadModel)
        SaveReloadESModel(regressionOutput, trainingLoss, inputVar, labelsVar, device, inputVarName, labelsVarName);
    m_prediction = regressionOutput;

    ProgressWriterPtr pw = MakeSharedObject<MyProgressWriter>(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    // Nesterov learner (SGD with momentum) 
    m_learner = MomentumSGDLearner(regressionOutput->Parameters(), m_learningRate, m_Momentum, true);
    m_trainer = CreateTrainer(regressionOutput, trainingLoss, m_prediction, { m_learner }, { pw });

    size_t numSamples = X.rows();
    m_inputData.resize(m_inputDim * numSamples);
    m_labelData.resize(m_outputDim * numSamples, 0);
    m_olsFittedValues.resize(numSamples);

    flattenXYData(numSamples, X, Y);

    NDShape inputShape({ m_inputDim });
    auto dim = inputShape.Dimensions();
    ValuePtr inputValue = Value::CreateSequence(inputShape, m_inputData, device,true);

    NDShape labelShape({ m_outputDim });
    ValuePtr labelValue = Value::CreateSequence(labelShape, m_labelData, device,true);

    ValuePtr outputValue, predictionErrorValue;

    //main training loop
    //at the moment CNTK C++ API lacks "reader" functions for taking data from memory.
    //the reader support the automatic minibatch extraction from full batch.
    //Here we are training full batch.


    if (m_printTrainingProgress)  std::cout << "OLS learning..." << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_iterationCount; ++i)
    {
        m_trainer->TrainMinibatch({ {inputVar, inputValue}, {labelsVar, labelValue} }, device);
        if (m_printTrainingProgress) m_trainer->SummarizeTrainingProgress();
    }



    //record fitted training weights
    getTrainingWeightsVaR();
    //get fitted values and VaR weights
    EvaluationSequenceUsingDense(m_trainer->EvaluationFunction(), m_inputData, m_olsFittedValues, false, device);

    if (m_printTrainingSummary)
    {
        std::unordered_map<Variable, ValuePtr> tmap = { {inputVar, inputValue} };
        m_trainer->TestMinibatch(tmap, device, false);
        m_trainer->SummarizeTestProgress();
    }

}



void RMLearning::flattenXYData(const size_t &numSamples, const Eigen::MatrixXd & X, const Eigen::MatrixXd & Y)
{
    //map X matrix to input data vector
    size_t j = 0;
    for (size_t i1 = 0; i1 < numSamples; ++i1)
    {
        for (size_t i2 = 0; i2 < m_inputDim; ++i2)
        {
            m_inputData[j] = (float)X(i1, i2);
            j++;
        }
    }

    //map Y matrix to label data vector
    j = 0;
    for (size_t i1 = 0; i1 < numSamples; ++i1)
    {
        for (size_t i2 = 0; i2 < m_outputDim; ++i2)
        {
            m_labelData[j] = (float)Y(i1, i2);
            j++;
        }
    }
}

//Neural network structure setup
inline FunctionPtr RMLearning::FullyConnectedFeedForwardRegressionNet(Variable input,
    size_t outputLayerDim,
    size_t hiddenLayerDim,
    size_t numHiddenLayers,
    const DeviceDescriptor& device,
    const std::function<FunctionPtr(const FunctionPtr&)>& nonLinearity,
    const std::wstring& outputName,
    unsigned long seed)
{
    assert(numHiddenLayers >= 1);
    auto regressionRoot = FullyConnectedDNNLayer(input, hiddenLayerDim, device, nonLinearity, L"", seed);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < numHiddenLayers; ++i)
        regressionRoot = FullyConnectedDNNLayer(regressionRoot, hiddenLayerDim, device, nonLinearity, L"", seed);

    //output layer
    regressionRoot = FullyConnectedLinearLayer(regressionRoot, outputLayerDim, device, outputName, seed);
    return regressionRoot;
}
```

With NN of say 3 hidden layers of dim 20, training full batches of say 20,000 records on 1,000 iterations takes about 2 seconds using GPU (with nearly zero utilisation) and 8 seconds using CPU (6 core Intel 100% utilised). Given that CNTK shields the developer from most of the low level detail of CUDA does it provide any API or parameters that may be used to increase utilisation? In my situation is the GPU likely waiting on CPU for something? What strategies have others found useful?

Comment: If GPU utilization is zero then you are not using GPU. GPU usage is either a turn on or turn off.

Comment: Snowflake this reply is not constructive. As I said I get a 4 times speedup using GPU relative to CPU but the GPU utilization is barely above zero. More likely the CUDA implementation has not been written well by Microsoft giving low occupancy. Quadro P3200 has 14 SMs and around 5 teraflops in 32 bit floating point. The speedup should be much better.